# C++ string to python limitation using swig

Tags: python, c++, string, limit, swig

I have recently bumped into a swig limitation related to the size of C++ std::string.

I have some C++ code returning a pair. I noticed that when the size of the string in the pair is smaller that 2*1024*1024*1024-64 (2GB) the pair properly returns and the string is mapped to a python native string. However if the string is greater than 2GB, then in python the string is not mapped anymore to a native python string. For example using the code below, and mapping through swig to python you can reproduce my error.

Environment:: SWIG Version 3.0.8, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, g++ 5.4.0; Python 2.7.12

```
/////////// bridge.h
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
pair<int, string> large_string(long sz);
long size_pstring(pair<int,string>& p);
void print_pstring(pair<int,string>& p);
string save_pstring(pair<int,string>& p);

//////////bridge.cc
#include "bridge.h"

pair<int, string> large_string(long sz){
 pair<int, string> pis;
 pis.first=20;
 pis.second=string(sz,'A');
 return pis;
}

long size_pstring(pair<int,string>& p){
 return p.second.size();
}

void print_pstring(pair<int,string>& p){
  cout<<"PSTRING: first="<<p.first<<" second.SZ="<<p.second.size()<<"\n";
  cout<<"First 100 chars: \n"<<p.second.substr(0,100)<<"\n";
}

string save_pstring(pair<int,string>& p){
  string fname="aloe.txt";
  std::ofstream ofile(fname.c_str());
  ofile<<p.second;
  ofile.close();
  return fname;
}
////////// bridge.i
%module graphdb

%include stl.i
%include "std_vector.i"

%{
#include "bridge.h"
%}
%include "bridge.h"
namespace std {
  %template(p_string)           pair<int,string>;
};
//////// makefile
all:
    swig -c++ -python bridge.i
    g++ -std=c++11 -fpic -c bridge.cc bridge_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7/
    g++ -shared *.o -o  _graphdb.so
```

Bellow I include a session in python showing that it is probably just a matter of how string is mapped and that most probably an int rather long is used to represent the size of string in swig bridge code.

```
>>> s=graphdb.large_string(12)
>>> print s
(20, 'AAAAAAAAAAAA')
>>> s=graphdb.large_string(2*1024*1024*1024)
>>> print s
(20, <Swig Object of type 'char *' at 0x7fd4205a6090>)
>>> l=graphdb.size_pstring(s)
>>> print l
2147483648
>>> fname = graphdb.save_pstring(s)
```

Saving the string to a file is correct and next I can load the file to a python string correctly.

So my question: does anybody know what swig config option I should change to allow large strings to be properly mapped to native python ?

--Thx

Comment: Are you sure that something is indeed wrong and it's not a matter of efficiency? Cause printing *2G* on screen is anything but smart, (and would probably take forever.)

Comment: Wasn't able to repro. Used *Lnx* (because `long` is 8bytes), *Python2* (because of `print`) and *swig3*. Also can't repro on *Python3*. Probably you are using an older *swig version. I can't install *swig2.0* without removing *swig3.0*, so I won't.

Comment: Found an *OSX* *VM* with *Python2.7.10* and *swig2.0.10*, but still couldn't reproduce. Output is *<Swig Object of type 'pair< int,std::string > \*' at 0x7f7b971bf8a0>*.

Comment: Indeed I am not printing the string in my app; It so happens that the print() exposes the limitation I am trying to fix. Pls have in mind that I tried to print a string slightly smaller than 2GB using teh above scenario and that works; python will start printing which means the string was properly mapped (i killed the process after  few secs :) ) ;

Comment: Details about environment: SWIG Version 3.0.8, Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, g++ 5.4.0; Python 2.7.12

Above I simplified a little as my application is a bit more complex. The pair <int, string> actually contains the status of some operation and the string is a json with some data extracted from a database. In my case whenver the string (json) is bigger than 2GB the json load ( result = json.loads(result_db.second) ) fails with an exception that it can't load from a <Swig Object of type 'char *' at 0x7fd4205a6090>

Comment: CristiFati, when you are saying you can't reproduce you imply that print will start printing the real string (AAA....) or you are saying that you get the "<Swig...> message ? if you get the swig message rather than AAAA... it means you reproduced my problem.

Comment: I was saying that I get the *SwigObject* output, for the 12 lengthted string as well. You should also post your *.i* file.

Comment: The post is updated to include the full code to reproduce the problem.